# Samsung S4 Android is not connecting using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, android, samsung

I remember this working before but for some reason it has stopped. When I plug my USB cable into the phone and laptop the device appears in the file manager but when I click on it I get

```
Unable to open MTP device '[usb:002,016]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps someone else, it was the USB cable. Annoyingly the cables I have from Samsung (one for my tablet, one for my phone) seem to be device specific and getting them mixed up will produce the above error and the device will not connect.

Would be nice if the error were a bit more user friendly but at least for now this answer is here to help anyone else that sees this problem.